# Is it possible to develop google glass apps using objective c?

Tags: objective-c, google-glass, google-api-objc-client

I have gone through a deep research on developing google glass apps using `objective c` ,but I have found that we should only use Java/Python/PHP to develop google glass apps. Since I am an objective c developer I am looking for some static library or framework for xcode, which is built to develop apps for google glass. Please give me any idea, is there any such frameworks/Library? Any of your suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: there is an alternative project hat uses GNUStep and there-for Objective-C http://hmdviking.blogspot.jp/?view=magazine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Google provides an Objective C API library at https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/ that includes generated routines for the Mirror API. You should probably also consult the documentation at https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/index for a broad understanding of how the Mirror API works.

Note that this will allow you to develop web services that work with Glass. It will not allow you to develop applications that run on Glass itself. It also will not allow you to write iOS applications that communicate directly with Glass - it will need a network connection to the Mirror server at Google and there may be some restrictions about how a callback will work.

Answer (score 0):

Android SDK is what you use to create .APK files to run on an android or google glass device.  It is based on the java platform.

Just like Prisoner says you can mess with the mirror API by sending cards to your device in almost any language via those starter kits.

If you are actually trying to make glassware you will need the Android SDK. Unless you are a very experienced programmer I wouldn't try to program in C to create apps going on glass.

On a side note: if you are a new programmer and are only experienced in C, try to learn python.  Python is great for programming in C with a variation called CPython.